# How to access visual composer template variable in php to get categories

Tags: wordpress, plugins

this is my code :

```
  add_shortcode( 'vc_post_cat', 'vc_post_cat_render' );
  function vc_post_cat_render() {
    $postId = '{{ post_data:ID }}';
   $cat = get_the_category($postId);
  }
```

but postId is not working for function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
add_shortcode( 'vc_gitem_custom_post_excerpt', 'vc_gitem_custom_post_excerpt_render' );
function vc_gitem_custom_post_excerpt_render( $atts )
{
  return '{{ excerpt_length:' . http_build_query( (array) $atts ) . ' }}';
}
```